# Embedded YouTube not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I've seen [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/YAJUPhr_ln4) on Google's product forums, but who knows when that will be answered, so hopefully someone here may know.

On [my site](http://www.mightyspring.com), the video will not display in Chrome (latest). It works fine in IE[x], FF, and Safari. In Chrome, the console shows this "warning":

> [blocked] The page at https://www.mightyspring.com/ ran insecure
>   content from
>   http://www.youtube.com/v/cFxF3lWsdPE?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=homepageVideo&version=3.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong and/or how to fix it? Or is this just a bug that will fix itself in the next release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this issue, the answer is because Chrome is properly blocking the site from loading a video not behind SSL. My live site is actually `https://` (see the "s"?) and I had the protocol as `http://`

Comment: Is there a setting to allow playing video from non-https URLs?